# Добавление фильтра в наличии, умный фильтр 1c-bitrix

Tags: битрикс, фильтр

Буду рад любой информации по реализации добавления фильтра "В наличии", в умный фильтр битрикса.
Пытался править файл script.js компонента catalog.smart.filter, но безуспешно. Может, есть какая то документация по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

Создал свойство AVAILABLE типа список, со значением "В наличии". После чего написал скрипт, который проходил по всем элементам инфоблока и проверял наличие на складах, также проверял не равна ли цена нулю (На сайте был написан костыль, который давал флаг "Не в наличии" товарам, у которых цена была равна нулю.), соответственно, если скрипт проходил по условиям, то выставлял значение свойства "В наличии", если нет, то оставлял не установленным или убирал значение "В наличии". Таким образом удалось решить вопрос.